# retrieving or reading router log

Tags: vbscript

I like to telnet to my router and login with password. I did it with VBS sucessfully with no time (I cheers myself) but then I think I need not just login to that router, I need to write/send some command like" show if config" into that router and I also did it. But then the last requirement, I need to take/get that "show if config" output to my computer I can't do this. Been looking around for any light, but I can't find. Anyone know how to take "show if config" output to my "D:/" directory?

Comment: Use a scriptable telnet like [`plink`](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.64/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink) instead of the `telnet` command shipped with Windows.

Comment: What is plink, I am sorry I am a noob. I read that to completes this job we can do also with TCL but I dont know it either. I just want to finish this job with vbscript, and just this little puzzle to solve, how can I read that stream text a.k.a the router's command output and save it to my desktop. Please.

Comment: Could you be bothered to follow the link to the program's documentation, that I already provided?